# v-autocomplete @change previous element

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a `v-autocomplete` and I want to get the previous item.

This is what I have:

```html
<v-autocomplete v-model="selectCPU"
label="CPU"
hint="CPU" 
persistent-hint
:items="cpus" item-text="id.model"
item-value="id.id" :rules="cpuRules"
:disabled="!selectBrand"
@change="myMethod();">
</v-autocomplete>
```

```js
myMethod () {
    var previousElement = ?
    var actualElement = this.selectCPU
}
```

I would also like to control the fact that if there is no previous item, do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a little and finding the @click event I decided to do the following:

I added a variable in data() called previousCPU

```html
<v-autocomplete v-model="selectCPU"
label="CPU"
hint="CPU" 
persistent-hint
:items="cpus" item-text="id.model"
item-value="id.id" :rules="cpuRules"
:disabled="!selectBrand"
@change="myMethod();"
@click="previousCPU = selectCPU">
</v-autocomplete>
```

```js
myMethod () {
    var previousElement = this.previousCPU
    var actualElement = this.selectCPU
}
```